# @Autowired Bean returning null

Tags: spring, javabeans

I am using third part library using jar in my spring boot application and created singleton bean of the class I need to use. However when I auto wire this bean, it always return null

Created singleton of the class from library and auto wiring the bean

```
@Configuration
public class IdGenConfig {   
    private static final Instant baseTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();

    @Bean//this too 3rd party lib class
    public MachineId concreteMachineId(){
        return new ConcreteMachineId();
    }

    @Bean(name = "camflakeIdGen")//this is 3rd party library
    public Camflake camflake(final MachineId machineId){
        return new Camflake(machineId, baseTime);
    }}

@Service
@Log4j2
public class IdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("camflakeIdGen")
    Camflake camflake;//here null

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            log.debug("generate(): action=generate; state=start; message=\"generating id\";");
            Long id = camflake.next();
            log.debug("generate(): action=generate; state=finish; message=\"generating id\";id={};",id);
            return id;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.fatal("generate(): action=generate; state=error; message=\"generating id\"; error=\"{}\";", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw new Exception(ErrorType.SYSTEM_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How and where do you get/create an instance of IdGenerator? Do you realize that Hibernate doesn't know and care about Spring?

Comment: Yes, looks like that. Hibernate creating new instance of idgenerator every time which is causing autowired to fail

Answer (score 0):

```
····
 @Bean(name = "camflakeIdGen")//this is 3rd party library
    public Camflake camflake(final MachineId machineId){
        return new Camflake(machineId, baseTime);
    }}
```

I think here is your wrong!

```
@Configuration
public class IdGenConfig {   
    private static final Instant baseTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();

    @Bean//this too 3rd party lib class
    public MachineId concreteMachineId(){
        return new ConcreteMachineId();
    }

    @Bean(name = "camflakeIdGen")// try this way!!
    public Camflake camflake(){
        return new Camflake(concreteMachineId(), baseTime);
    }}
```